# Convergence set of power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to find the convergence set of the power series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ln\big[1+\big(\dfrac{1}{n}\big)\big](x+2)^n$.

So using the ratio test:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{ln\big[1+\big(\dfrac{1}{n+1}\big)\big]|x+2|^{n+1}}{ln\big[1+\big(\dfrac{1}{n}\big)\big]|x+2|^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{ln\big[1+\big(\dfrac{1}{n+1}\big)\big]}{ln\big[1+\big(\dfrac{1}{n}\big)\big]} \cdot |x+2|$

Using L'Hopital's rule we have: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{ln\big[1+\big(\dfrac{1}{n+1}\big)\big]}{ln\big[1+\big(\dfrac{1}{n}\big)\big]} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{n}{2+n} = 1$.

So $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{ln\big[1+\big(\dfrac{1}{n+1}\big)\big]}{ln\big[1+\big(\dfrac{1}{n}\big)\big]} \cdot |x+2| = |x+2|$. So the series converges for $|x+2| \lt 1$ and diverges for $|x+2| \gt 1$.

**Is this correct? Is this the convergence set? Is this the easiest way to test?**

Comment: I think you forgot to show what happens on the boundary

Comment: How do I test the bounds?

Comment: What happens if $|x +2| = 1$? You have two $x$s, plug them back into the original series and see what happens.

Comment: You are going to have to use the alternating series test it would seem.

Comment: You can use the Hadamard formula for the radius of convergence.Whether it's easier in this case may be a toss-up.